# Reading two files using one variable?

Tags: python

I've been searching online and I can't find anything so I'm not sure if it's possible, but is there any way I can read two text files and put them into one variable so I can return the data stored in that variable? So far I just copied and pasted the same for loop for each file like this:

```
import re


def read_files():
    with open('sample_data_01.txt') as f1, open('sample_data_02.txt') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            pattern = '^en.v\s(\w+)(\D+)(\d+)'
            match = re.findall(pattern, line)
            print(match)
            for line in f2:
                pattern = '^en.v\s(\w+)(\D+)(\d+)'
                match = re.findall(pattern, line)
                print(match)
        return
```

Comment: Why do you have nested `for` clauses? Just process each file sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `for` to loop through the files so you don't need to do it manually, also when using `regex` get used of adding `r` in front of the string pattern so you don't escape unwanted characters, for example:

```py
import re


def read_files():
    matches = []
    for file_path in ('sample_data_01.txt', 'sample_data_02.txt'):
        with open(file_path) as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                pattern = r'^en.v\s(\w+)(\D+)(\d+)'
                match = re.findall(pattern, line)
                print(match)
                matches.extend(match)
    return matches
```

Comment: You probably want to put a line at the top, outside the loop: `matches = []`, and then another line below the `print` statement: `matches.extend(match)`, followed by `return matches` at the very bottom, outside of both loops.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay that is true, however, if he only wants to print the matches then there is no need for that.

Comment: I think he wants to return all matches: "*but is there any way I can read two text files and put them into one variable so I can return the data stored in that variable?*" `matches` would be the one variable.

Comment: Though, the OP should be able to attempt that himself. SO isn't a code writing service, after all.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay oh, again, you are absolutely right, I updated the answer to include the list of matches based on your suggestion. Thanks for spotting that.